# Restriction: polynomial time decision of instance is why needed to "decision Problem"?

Tags: complexity-theory, computability, decision-problem

I am reading book "combinatorial optimization 3rd edition(Bernhard Korte、 Jens Vygen)".

(latest version is sixth.)

There are some discriptions in this book that I don't understand

> Not all binary strings are instances of Hamiltonian Circuit but only those
>   representing an undirected graph. For most interesting decision problems the in-
>   stances are a proper subset of the 0-1-strings. We require that we can decide in
>   polynomial time whether an arbitrary string is an instance or not:

- quote from p350

> decision problem is pair P = (X,Y), where X is a language decidable in polynomial time.

- quote p351

Why decision problem required that decide in polynomial time whether an arbitrary string is an instance or not?

I can't found any reasons of this restriction in the book.

Comment: Decision problems are not necessarily decided in polynomial time, I believe that the citations are lacking some context.

Comment: This description is written in chap 15-3 P and NP(chap 15 is "NP-Completeness") . I think this restriction may be need to be NP class.